# Железобетонный random java

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа

Пишу небольшую игру, в ней генерируется случайное число, от этого числа зависит весь исход уровня, т.е надо его максимально рандомизировать, что бы не было возможности заранее узнать это число.

Пока реализовал так :

```
 Random rnd = new Random(currentTimeMillis());
 int number = 1 + rnd.nextInt(100 - 1 + 1);
```

Тот же рандом.орг, вроде бы, отталкивается от погодных условий или что-то типа того, что бы сделать все максимально рандомным. Можете мне подсказать способы, как улучшить рандомизацию и повысить защиту кода ? (чтобы злые юзеры не смогли легко воздействовать на выдачу рандомного числа)

Comment: Посмотрите класс SecureRandom

Comment: Вам не нужно ничего больше, особенно в таких небольших диапазонах. Более крутые алгоритмы могут применяться в криптографии, но и там предсказать без очень узкоспециализированых знаний + достаточного набора данных невозможно. Так что используйте рандом и не заморачивайтесь )

Comment: на него можно повлиять? О_о

Comment: спасибо всем за помощь. 
@Flippy насчет повлиять хз, но предсказать можно, простой рандом (опыт еще с других языков)